# Formatting specific set of cells on all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

The code below doesn't give any error, but it isn't doing exactly what I want it to do, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The purpose of the code is to add a formulae into specific cells in all the sheets based on a criteria on each sheet. This part of the formulae is working perfectly fine (if it can be made shorter, then that would be a bonus). The part that isn't working properly is the formatting section of the code. I want the defined formatting to occur on all the sheets, but its only happening on the first "Summary" sheet.

As I mentioned earlier there is no error messages, it runs through fine, but only changing the formatting of the cells in the Summary sheet and not on all the sheets.

Any advice would be much appreciated:)

```
Sub Summary()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng, Rng2 As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set Sht = wb1.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set Rng = Sht.Range("A6:A" & Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each cell In Rng
       Set ws = wb1.Sheets(cell.Text)
       Select Case ws.Range("A4").Value
                Case "Standard Kitchen Template"
                ws.Range("G10").Formula = "=Sum(e2167:e2182, e2179:e2885)"
                ws.Range("H10").Formula = "=Sum(e49:e54, e291:e296)"
                ws.Range("I10").Formula = "=Sum(e125:e139)"
                ws.Range("J10").Formula = "=Sum(e213:e286, e299:e302)"
                ws.Range("K10").Formula = "=Sum(e168:e208)"
                ws.Range("L10").Formula = "=Sum(e156:e162)"
                ws.Range("O10").Formula = "=Sum(e142:e148)"
                ws.Range("Q10").Formula = "=Sum(e14:e48, e56:e78)"

                Case "Standard Bathroom Template"
                ws.Range("G10").Formula = "=Sum(e334:e339, e347:e1050)"
                ws.Range("H10").Formula = "=Sum(e185:e317)"
                ws.Range("I10").Formula = "=Sum(e79:e97)"
                ws.Range("J10").Formula = "=Sum(e68:e70, e323:e326)"
                ws.Range("K10").Formula = "=Sum(e134:e178)"
                ws.Range("L10").Formula = "=Sum(e115:e132)"
                ws.Range("O10").Formula = "=Sum(e99:e107)"
                ws.Range("Q10").Formula = "=Sum(e29:e33, e41:e50)"

End Select
Next cell   '<------The code below this line is the one not working properly

For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
 With Sht
        Range("G10").Select
        With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 12611584
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("H10").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("I10").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("J10").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("K10").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("L10").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10498160
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("O10").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("Q10").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    End With

     Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets` loop you are not using the `Sht` object. You are referring to the ranges within your `ActiveSheet` because your `.Select` methods are not prefixed with a `.` which connects the ranges to your `Sht` object.

For example after your `With Sht` you need your next line to be `.Range("G10").Select` not `Range("G10").Select` - notice the `.` at the beginning.

You have also already used the variable of `Sht` earlier in your code to define `wb1.Worksheets("Summary")` so it would be best to use a different variable in your loop to avoid confusion.

However, it is always advised not to use `Select` as this slows down code. Try this instead:

```
For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With Sht
        With .Range("G10").Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 12611584
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Range("H10").Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Range("I10").Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 49407
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Range("J10").Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Range("K10").Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 5296274
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Range("L10").Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 10498160
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Range("O10").Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Range("Q10").Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = -0.149998474074526
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With

Next Sht
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly now. when I added the . in front of Range, it was giving me an error "Select method of Range class failed", but when I copy pasted your code it works perfectly. was there something else that was incorrect in my original code?

Comment: I changed `Next` to `Next Sht` and tidied some of the indentations to help with the visibility but the syntax remained the same except for what I explained in the answer. It's always best to avoid `Select` though! Just refer to the range directly!